# How do I read a string into a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to turn a some strings into a list.

I have have various strings called elementX, which I want to turn into a list with the same structure as Options.

```
#turn string into list
element1 = {'label': '26', 'value': '26'}
element2 = {'label': '28', 'value': '28'}
element3 = {'label': '29', 'value': '29'}
type(element1)

options=[
        {'label': '26', 'value': '26'},
        {'label': '28', 'value': '28'},
        {'label': '29', 'value': '29'},
     ]
```

Goal is it to offer the labels of the string as Options in a Dropdown.dcc from Dash.

Comment: `options = [element1, element2, element3]` ? Otherwise, show the `input` and `output` required

Comment: On a different note: if the labels/values for your actual problem (not just the example) are numbers, you might want to use a different dash component like the [slider](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/slider)

Answer (score 0):

@zacha2, what is wrong with `[element1, element2, element3]`?

Keep in mind that until 3.6 or 3.7, dictionaries are unordered so when you print them, the 'label' and 'value' tuples might be transposed but this doesn't affect the functionality of the dictionaries.

Or do you have an arbitrary number of dictionaries called `elementNNN` and you want to collect them all at runtime? First I would reconsider your design so that you have instead something like `elements[]` instead. But if you really need to do this for an arbitrary number of elementN variables, you can use:

```py
[v for (k,v) in locals().items if k.startswith('element')]
```

The `locals()` function will return a dictionary of local variables and their associated values.